# Pronic number in c++ error

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,i=0,j=1;
    cin>>n;
    int m;
    while(m!=n){
        m=i*j;
        cout<<m;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to display Pronic Number ie . 0,2,6,12,20,30,42...                                         When I insert value of **n** as Pronic Number Code run fine ... and desire output is given..                       Bug is when you insert value of *n=15* **while    loop** goes to infinity but i want to display till 15 or less than
   15..  Here 15 is not a Pronic Number..

Comment: `while (m!=n)` <-- You are reading from `m` before initializing it. This invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Since your loop condition is `m != n` and `m` is each pronic number in turn, the loop will only exit if `n` is also a pronic number. If you want the `n`:th number, loop `n` times.

Comment: `m` is not initialized before used.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just exploit the fact that any given n'th pronic number, it is nothing more than the sum of the first n positive even integers. I.e. 0, 2 (2), 6 (2+4), 12 (2+4+6), 20 (2+4+6+8), etc. E.g. [something like **this**](https://ideone.com/8SbkUN), which prints the first 100 pronic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `m` before using it, plus change your condition to stop the loop when `m>n`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,i=0,j=1;
    cin>>n;
    int m=0;
    while(m<=n){
        cout<<m<<" ";   
        i++;
        j++;
        m=i*j;
    }
    return 0;
}
```